# Problem adding multiple images to a Post in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to upload multiple images to the same post but I had some issues with the request

```
$data = Post::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'content' => $request->content,
        'category_id' => $request->category,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id
    ]);

    $user = auth()->user();
    $post = new Post();
    $post = $user->posts()->create($data);
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $files = $request->file('image');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $name = time().'-'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $name = str_replace('','-', $name);
            echo $name."<br>";
            $file->move('post-images',$name);
            $post->image()->create(['name'=>$name]);
        }
    }
    
    if($request->tags){
        $post->tags()->attach($request->tags);
    }
    return redirect(route('posts.index'))->with('success','Articulo creado!');
```

The problem I have is that I can't find how to pass the `"image"` parameter inside the `Image Table` when creating the post, since the image is being registered in another `database`.

[image]

Another way to do it could be:

```
$data = $request->all();
```

But in this case I have the problem that I can't find how to associate `"category"` to `"category_id"` in the table.

Any suggestions or recommendations on how I should solve the problem?

Comment: what is the `image` parameter?? you are saving image to the database with `$post->image()->create(['name'=>$name]);` and this is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, I have, but the problem is that in the Post::create is asking me for the image value but that value is store in another database, I'm a little confused about it actually. I edit the post and add the error presented to me

Comment: you have one to many relationship with post and image..you don't need the image column in the post table..just drop it..

Comment: Oh you were right, I forgot to drop that column from the migration. Now is working perfectly, thank you.